# Finding 95% of values per group in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table with data like this (table actually contains thousands of rows)

```
Group   Value
A           1
B           2
C           4
A           7
A           8
B           3
C           8
A           6
B           8
C           8
```

I need to find 95% of value from each group.

For example, if group A contains 1000 rows then I need to return 950 rows (1000 * 95%).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`NTILE()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions115.htm#SQLRF00680), which splits a result-set into buckets - for 95% split into 20 buckets and take 1-19. The following query will give you 20 buckets per group in the order of values ascending.

```
with ordered_data as (
select a.*, ntile(20) over (partition by g order by v) as n
  from the_data a
       )
select g, v
  from ordered_data
 where n <= 19
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/40592)

If you don't have an explicit order by in here then the 5% of rows that are discarded will be arbitrary - this may not matter to you, in which case remove it.

If you don't want it per group it might be simpler to count the number of rows and then restrict the number of rows returned to a percentage of the count:

```
with ordered_data as (
select a.*, count(*) over () as ct
  from <your_table> a
 order by v
       )
select g, v
  from ordered_data
 where rownum <= 0.95 * ct
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/40592)

Though, adding a partition clause to the `COUNT()` here will have a similar effect, i.e. `count(*) over (partition by g)`

Comment: +1 , sounds like what i wanted. i will implement this in my query and let you know it works ..thanks Ben